# Count observations over rolling 30 days windows with restrictions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My idea is to count observations (grouped by Id's) within 30 days windows. My problem is that I want to introduce an exception in the counting process: if during the 30 days analyzed there is an observation that will be discarded (because n> 1) the count is only constructed with the data not discarded. (n is the variable that counts the number of observations within 30 days windows).

Example

```
id  date
1   1/1/2021
1   22/1/2021
1   1/2/2021
```

```
Code: 
test<-test%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(n=sapply(seq(length(date)),
                  function(x) sum(between(date[1:x],date[x]-days(30),date[x]))))
```

```
id  date    n
1   1/1/2021    1
1   22/1/2021   2
1   1/2/2021    2
1   3/3/2021    2
1   2/2/2021    3
1   7/7/2021    1
```

Expected result:

```
id  date    n   nexpected
1   1/1/2021    1   1
1   22/1/2021   2   2
1   1/2/2021    2   1
1   3/3/2021    2   2
1   2/2/2021    3   1
1   7/7/2021    1   1
```

---

Alternative explanation

I just want to keep an observation (grouped by ID) for every 30 days. I want to do this by creating a variable that tells me which observations are left inside (1) and which ones are outside (0) of the filter.

Comment: Why is nexpected = 2 for `3/3/2021`? It's not within 30 days of `1/2/2021`.

Comment: Because of the observation 2/2/2021 (d/m/y) (dif=29 days)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but `lubridate::floor_date` is often useful in those situations:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

test %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy(date)) %>%
  group_by(id, floor = floor_date(date, 'month')) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number())

     id date       floor          n
  <int> <date>     <date>     <int>
1     1 2021-01-01 2021-01-01     1
2     1 2021-01-22 2021-01-01     2
3     1 2021-02-01 2021-02-01     1
```

Comment: My idea is that obs 3 is n=1 because obs 2 must not be counted because n=2 in obs 2.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you edit your question with an example where my solution does not work?